# In SQL Server Management 2012, how do you set the SQL Memory to Dynamic instead of fixed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When you go to **Server Properties>Memory** you can see Server Memory Options and Other memory options. How do you let SQL determine the min and max memory so that we don't have to set it to a fixed level? I'm looking for a way to set this dynamically if possible... THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL will use as much memory as possible up to the MAX memory memory setting. You really need to only change this when ever you change the physical memory on that server. The MAX memory setting should be less than the total server memory. It should be high enough so that a good 90 percent of RAM is used in the task manager. This is a good starting point, but there are many articles to help you dial that number in. Here is one place to start: [Server Memory Server Configuration Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options)